# How can i make VPN Tunnel Between GCP Cloud VPN and my PC ubuntu?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn

How can i make VPN Tunnel Between GCP Cloud VPN and my Ubuntu/windows VM?
It is for DEMO/test purpose.
Can anyone help me to configure the same.

Comment: Please read the tag description for [tag:vpn].

Answer (score 0):

For a simple OpenVPN method, you can check [OpenVPN Access Server](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/openvpn-access-server-200800/openvpn-access-server) on Google Cloud Marketplace and use OpenVPN client on Windows / Ubuntu on the client side.

Using [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview) requires creating a Cloud Router that might be too overkill for your case.

If you want hands-on solutions for Cloud VPN. I suggested you check [Cloud VPN labs on Google Cloud Skills Boost](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/catalog?keywords=vpn) which has step-by-step on how to set up Cloud VPN.